# iPad Force page curl transition

Tags: ios, ipad, uipageviewcontroller, page-curl

I am trying to force a page curl transition on my UIPageViews without any gesture. I would like my pages to transition with the page curl effect automatically. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, you would like to automatically slide the views ?
If yes, you can use `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: target: selector: userInfo: repeats:]`

with custom function:
eg:

```
- (void)animateViews {

[UIView transitionWithView:_viewsArray[_selectedPosition]
                      duration:1.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
                    animations:^ {
                        _viewsArray[_selectedPosition].alpha = .0f;
                        _viewsArray[_selectedPosition + 1 > _viewsArray.count ? 0 : _selectedPosition + 1 ].alpha = 1.0f;
                    }
                    completion:^{
                        _selectedPosition++;
                    }];
}
```

Where _viewsArray is the array of animatable view, e.g image views etc. and _selectedPosition is the position of displayed view within the array.

If using blocks I would suggest you to use weak and strong reference.
This is very simple solution, so you can adapt it as you want.

Maybe it could be better to use UITableView or UICollectionView with its methods
willDisplayCell:
and within this method use an page curl animation.

You can also try to search [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org).
At least you can give it a try to find any library that uses custom view transitions ;-)